# MySQL Call Stored procedure from another stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, procedures, mysql-error-1146

Sorry for long POST:
Is it possible that I can call a  Stored Procedures from another
Stored procedure in MySQL.
For example:
I have two tables (test and testcomp):
With the structures below:

### -- Table structure for table `test`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
    `t_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`t_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

and

### -- Table structure for table `testcomp`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testcomp` (
    `c_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `t_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
    `place` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`c_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Now I populated test table with:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`t_id`, `name`) VALUES
    (1, 'foo'),
    (2, 'bar'),
    (3, 'ma');
```

and table testcomp with:

```
INSERT INTO `testcomp` (`c_id`, `t_id`, `place`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 'gugs'),
    (2, 2, 'nyanga'),
    (3, 1, 'gugs'),
    (4, 3, 'skom');
```

Now if I have 2 Procedures:

First QryTestComp:

```
SELECT t_id, place FROM TestComp
```

The one above works as the just querying normal table:
But the Second One QryTestPlac, which calls the above procedure:

```
SELECT * FROM Test INNER JOIN QryTestComp ON Test.t_id = QryTestComp.t_id
```

Comes with a error:

It says  Error: 1146  (42S01): Table 'mydb.qrytestcomp' doesn't exist.
It not a table but a procedure.

Pointer, please.

### Regards,

--Jongi

Answer (score 5):

you can't join onto a stored procedure, perhaps using views might be more suitable ?

Comment: Alternatively, consider selecting into a temporary table from the stored procedure, then joining on that.  Views make more sense, though.

Comment: Thanks, the views work like charm, that is what I wanted! Have a great day